# Android facebook bottom bar animation

Tags: android, facebook, android-animation

I want to implement a slide up/slide down animation on bottom bar when scrolling the screen up/down.

Implementation has to be like in facebook app when the user slide up/down the bottom options bar slowly slides up/down .

I tried using scrollview to get the scrollchanged method to identify the scrolling behaviour of user and hide the bar based on the events.the tricky part is how to animate it slowly based on user slide up/down.

tried using moveup/move down animation but it was not fluid as the next animation starts when the first one ends . so the movement of bottom bar is more animated.

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper name to that behavior is "quick return pattern" and you can implement it with this gist:

https://gist.github.com/JohNan/df776dc4926a1676cc05

Answer (score 0):

Referring from the post of @baniares

https://gist.github.com/JohNan/df776dc4926a1676cc05

Used the on scroll method to compute the scroll of slideup/down and settranslate method to update my view.

```
public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int newX,
            int newY, int oldX, int oldY) {

 if (scrollup)
 {
  <View>.setTranslationY(0);
 }
 else
 {
  <View>.setTranslationY(position+1);
 }
}
```

The value 0 should be used in .settranslateY to bring to original postion of view. Increasing the value will translate the view to make it slide down.